# Hyphenation and section titles with geometry

Tags: sectioning, margins, hyphenation, geometry, classicthesis

I am using `classicthesis` and the `geometry` package for my thesis.

Some section titles are not hyphenated correctly, but instead reach into the margin. It seem not to be possible to use, e.g., `\-`, to hyphenate the section title at the wanted position. This seems to be related to `geometry`...

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,
               a4paper,
               footinclude=true,
               headinclude=true,
               titlepages
               %draft
               ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[linedheaders,
            eulermath,
            eulerchapternumbers,
            parts,
            floatperchapter]{classicthesis} 

\usepackage[left=4cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage\part{Introduction and Background}

\chapter{Research questions}

\section[Research questions for study 1 ``Meta-analysis of
    neurostructural alterations in dyslexia'']{Research questions for study 1 ``Meta-analysis of
    neuro\-structural alterations in dyslexia''}} 
\sectionmark{Research questions for study 1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As a side-remark: When you are using KOMA classes, i would strongly recommand the `typearea` package of the KOMA bundle to use instead of the `geometry` package.

Comment: Can you please give the list of warning that you get? Is it maybe this type of warning?: > Underfull \hbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not related to `geometry`, but rather to the fact that you don't use the `pdfspacing` option; without it `classicthesis` employs `soul` for letterspacing the small caps titles and this has problems with hyphenation.

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  footinclude=true,
  headinclude=true,
  titlepages,
  %draft,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
  pdfspacing, % <-- added
  linedheaders,
  eulermath,
  eulerchapternumbers,
  parts,
  floatperchapter,
]{classicthesis} 

\usepackage[left=4cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Introduction and Background}

\chapter{Research questions}

\section{Research questions for study 1 ``Meta-analysis of
    neurostructural alterations in dyslexia''}
\sectionmark{Research questions for study 1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this changes the font, right? It is not palatino anymore...

Comment: @user21932 I don't know what you're saying: that clearly *is* Palatino. And my log file confirms what my eyes are seeing.

Comment: sorry, I just realized that it is indeed Palatino, but in my thesis, adding `pdfspacing` changes the spacing of the spaced low small caps letters so dramatically that they are right next to each other, what did look like another font to me... Now I have the problem that I do not know where this problem comes from. Using your code works, but using it in my thesis results in the strange spacing -- strangely, when I use a MWE with my whole preamble including `pdfspacing`, it looks good, but when I use my whole thesis, it does not?!?

Comment: Ah, OK, it seems to be related to `draft` -- apparently when set, it changes the spacing, when turned of it looks as expected. Do you know whether this is intended behavior? I think it's strange because I use draft to look for overful boxes, and when the font spacing is changed, this does not make sense anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not related to the`geometry` package *per se*, but only to the width of the text block that's in effect. The real problem is that TeX apparently doesn't "know" all the permissible hyphenation points in the word `neurostructural`. Specifically, TeX doesn't know about the hyphenation point between "neuro" and "structural".

If you provide the instruction

```
\hyphenation{neu-ro-struc-tu-ral}
```

in the preamble, the problem with the overfull line in the sectioning header goes away. Actually, there's a *tiny bit* of overhang left, but it's so small as to be hardly noticeable.

[image]

Comment: The `geometry` "effect" is setting a value of `\textwidth` where the lack of hyphenation happens to come in to play.

Comment: yeah, I did this, but it still produces overhang as you mention. Plus, when I specify `neu-rostructural`, it does not break there...

Comment: @Mico Right. That is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @user21932 - I guess you're facing a trade-off between having a good hyphenation point (after "neuro") while getting a very slight exceedance of the text block vs. no exceedance of the text block but getting a (typographically) inferior hyphenation point after "neu".

Comment: @AndrewSwann - OK, I'll rephrase the opening sentence of my answer.