# classicthesis + pdfspacing --> problems with footnote in chapter title

Tags: sectioning, footnotes, classicthesis

I had the problem stated in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141430/hyphenation-and-section-titles-with-geometry) thread

I now want to use `pdfspacing`, but this seems not to work with the way I defined footnotes in chapter titles.

See this example. Without `pdfspacing`, it compiles, with it does not:

```
\documentclass[12pt,
               a4paper,
               footinclude=true,
               headinclude=true,
               titlepages,
               %draft
               ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[pdfspacing,
            linedheaders,
            eulermath,
            eulerchapternumbers,
            parts,
            floatperchapter]{classicthesis} 


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage\part{Introduction and Background}

\chapter[Chapter Title]
    {Chapter Title\hspace{1.5pt}\protect\footnotemark}
    \chaptermark{Chapter Title}
    \label{ch:chaptertile}

\footnotetext{this chapter has been published as: XYZ}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\footnotemark` doesn't work in `\chapter` with `classicthesis` and, in my opinion, it's good news.

Comment: it does work when one comments out pdfspacing. Could you maybe point out an alternative? I am supposed to say in a footnote that the chapter was published... Thanks!

Comment: Footnote the first paragraph.

Comment: you mean to add the footnote at the end of the first paragraph?! My thesis advisor explicitly asked for a footnote at the chapter title :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trick `\spacedallcaps` into thinking it hasn't to do something special:

```
\chapter[Chapter Title]
    {Chapter Title\mbox{\protect\footnotemark}}
    \chaptermark{Chapter Title}
    \label{ch:chaptertile}

\footnotetext{this chapter has been published as: XYZ}
```

Comment: @user21932 Try reproducing it with a minimal example.

Comment: sorry, it appeared because I had pdfspacing commented out...